# PHP debugging breakpoint not hit when somebody hits the URL from a different machine

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have enabled XDebug and configured PhpStorm like this:

[image]

This is my PHP.ini configuration file:

```
zend_extension = "c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\zend_ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I have put my WAMP online. So anybody could type in my IP:Port combination and the website gets loaded fine. When I visit a URL like my IP:port from my machine the debug breakpoints hit fine. But when somebody else from a different machine hits my IP:port the page is loaded fine but the breakpoints don't get hit on my machine.

I want that whenever somebody hits the URL from a different machine as well my breakpoints should get hit on my machine.

Is there any extra setting that I need to do for that?

Comment: 1) xdebug will not be triggered automatically by default (what's the point of debugging every single page, especially if code runs fine). You need to tell xdebug that you want to debug it. It can be done by passing special xdebug parameter together with page request (usually via COOKIE; but can also be done via GET/POST parameter -- https://xdebug.org/docs/remote -- "HTTP Debug Sessions" section). Usually people use xdebug browser extension to set such cookie (the easiest way).

Comment: 2) You may want to specify exact host where xdebug will be connecting to (where your IDE is running) e.g. `xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1`. It's possible that in your setup it tries to connect back to the original machine (where the requests comes from) -- you need to see xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output to see whole current config

Comment: 3) Is ` IP:Port ` that you and your friend (person from another computer) uses to access your site is the same? If they are different .. then PhpStorm will require separate config (as on your screenshot -- the "Host" must match the requested one)

Comment: 4) If you want to **debug every single request** (regardless of xdebug cookie etc) -- then you need to use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini (do not forget to restart your Apache/PHP)

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks Do you mean the parameters like ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=10961 I already added that as well but didn't hit my breakpoint. Using cookie is not possible. Adding something in the URL is the only option.

Comment: Collect xdebug logs -- it should tell what is going on there (if xdebug actually tries to debug/connect to IDE or not) -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: @Lazyone: Yes I have the code on my machine and PHPStorm on my machine as well. My friend types in the IP:Port and I want my PHPStorm to catch that debug breakpoint. I did set xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 as well but no luck so far.

Comment: A) xdebug logs + [Detailed PhpStorm log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs) to see what is happening inside B) xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser.

Comment: @LazyOne: The xdebug does not update  when I hit the URL from a different machine. Should the host/port be my external IP / port or internal ? https://gyazo.com/da8e9e0c111c6c9fe4e395d339354c24 I tried it with both and haven't succeeded in both so far.

Comment: What sort of IP:ports do you use then (when accessing local and from different machine). Xdebug should generate the log as long as it sees "debug-this" parameter (or configured to debug every single request). If it does not -- maybe the code you are running runs on another server/port where another php interpreter (and hence different php.ini) is used? Right now I may only guess what is happening on your end as I see no detailed info from you.

Comment: @LazyOne: If I visit external IP:Port from my machine the XDebug log is generated fine. But if somebody else types in my external IP:Port the website is loaded fine but XDebug log is not generated. Hope this is clear? Do you want me to attach the log file when I type in my external IP:Port?

Comment: If it's not generated for the case you needed then it will be useless, unfortunately. You better try to figure out why it's not generated. Double check that PHP (and therefore xdebug) can see that special xdebug parameter or that remote_autostart is indeed enabled. No other clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting remote_host in your php.ini

https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_host

I'm guessing this is for testing only, but be aware that it will make you page hang if it's trying to serve more than one request at a time.

Comment: Thanks Parris. Yes this is for testing only.  I set the xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1 in my php.ini restarted the wamp server but still doesn't hit the breakpoint.